# A real number being computable

Tags: logic, computability

In my text, it says that a real number $r \in \mathbb{R}$ is computable iff given $n$ one can compute $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\left|r-q\right| \leq 2^{-n}$.

Can anyone show why it is the case?

(Another version of this is $r = \lim_n q_n$ for a computable sequence $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of rationals such that $\left|r-q\right| \leq 2^{-n}$ for each $n$. If possible, can anyone also show how these two are equal?)

Comment: The third paragraph seems to indicate that you view the first paragraph as a definition. Then what's the meaning of the second paragraph? What does it mean to show why a definition is the case?

Comment: @joriki removed definition. Oh well. my mistake.

Comment: OK, if it's not a definition, it would make sense to provide the definition of computable number that you're using, because it sure looks like one possible definition of that term. Have you looked at [the definitions in the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number#Formal_definition)?

Comment: what does it mean "can compute"? Because I can compute 0 and than I can add $2^{-n}$ as many times as I need. So every real number would be computable.

Comment: How do you know when to stop?

Comment: What textbook are you using?

Comment: So what's the definition of "computable"? I would guess that the first section of your question **is** the definition which would make the question somewhat wierd. Why would one ask why it is the case that the definition says?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, your first question seems to be unanswerable without a definition of computable (for real numbers). So I will just show you why the two conditions you provided for $r \in \mathbb{R}$ being computable are equivalent.

Suppose that given $n$, one can compute $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|r-q| \leq 2^{-n}$. There is actually a slight subtlety here: it must also be assumed that this ability to compute $q$ is *uniform in $n$*; that is, there must be a single algorithm that given $n$, produces $q$. With this in mind, the equivalence of the definitions becomes clear. Since $q$ depends upon $n$ we should really call it $q_{n}$. And there you have it!: the sequence $(q_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is computable, $r = \lim q_{n}$ and $|r-q_{n}| \leq 2^{-n}$.

(The converse direction is (or at least, should be) even clearer. But let me know if it's not.)

You should convince yourself that the abovementioned uniformity really is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There is a natural definition of computability for real numbers. Let us focus, for simplicity, on the interval [0,1[ . Any real number r in such an interval has a (say, binary) expansion .r0 r1 r2 .... where ri is the i-th symbol in such expansion. This essentially defines a bijection between [0,1[
and the set of functions N->{0,1}. So, we say that the real number is computable when the corresponding function is (in the formal sense of computability theory).

In practical terms, this means that a real number is computable when we have an *effective* way to compute it with an arbitrary precision, and both definitions in the question are alternative ways to state this. Since we have much less algorithms than reals, it obviously follows that most real numbers are *not* computable.

To make a few examples, all rational numbers are trivially computable, but many irrationals numbers are computable too, since we have effective techniques to compute their expansions (e.g. we know how to compute π, or e, or √2 with arbitrary precision).

To make an examples of a not computable real number, we can start from an undecidable problem, such as, say, the diagonal problem for Turing machines. 
Let Mi be the i-th Turing machines in some effective enumeration, and let us define the i-symbol in the expansion of r in the following way

```
    ri = 1 if Mi terminates on input i
         0 otherwise
```

then, r is not computable since otherwise we would solve the termination problem.

In fact, computability theory is sometimes also called effective analysis, since it precisely deals with effectively computable reals.